# Regex compilation error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i am searching for a regular expression which removes an `x` at the beginning of a path. Accepted path separators are `\`, `/` and `.` The path can also start with one of these separators but it don't have to.

According to [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) it is working but PHP throws the following error:

```
Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 24
```

and here is the regex:

```
/^([\/\.\\]?)X([\/\.\\]{1})/i
```

What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: Could you add the line where you use the regex in your script?
First instinct: use single quotes ' instead of double quotes " around your regex, otherwise PHP removes the escapes which are for PCRE

Comment: To escape a \ you have to use 3 or 4 backslashes \\\

Comment: Replace `\\]` with `\\\\]`. Escaping backslashes in PHP is a little awkward.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen not only in PHP :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are escaping `]` at the end

You can instead use [preg_quote()](http://php.net/preg_quote) which puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax.

Also, there's no need to escape `.`(if it's is in character class)

Comment: cool, didn't know that function - that'll save a lot of confusion when it comes to escaping escapes for PCRE :)

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all x that stand right after every non alphabet or non digit char.

$result = preg_replace('/(?<=\W)x/', '', $subject);

Comment: unfortunatly that's not what i was/am looking for